# JSON object Undefined in Angular even tho i can access it directly

Tags: angular, typescript

Could not find anything that is exactly like my error, i've tried other solutions for SIMILAR errors tho, but they did not work either.

JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "somedata": "value",
    "somedata2": "somevalue1",
    "somedata3": "somevalue2",
  },
etc etc
```

Just a normal JSON right.

Typescript that works

```
let g = json[1]
console.log(g.somedata)
```

Doing this outputs the correct property : "value"

Typescript that does not work

```
while (a < 20) {
    console.log(json[a].name)
    a++;
}
```

This doesn't work either

```
    for (var index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
    let g = json[index].name
    console.log(g)
}
```

And this also does not work

```
var a = 1;
console.log(json[a].name)
```

Also removing the property .name gives "Undefined" in all above samples but not the first sample, that does work and gives me the whole first json object.

The same error i get in all examples trying is:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at GamesService.FetchAllGamesFromJSON (games.service.ts:16)
at HomeComponent.FetchGameData (home.component.ts:12)
at HomeComponent_Template_button_click_0_listener (home.component.html:1)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15265)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15303)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:406)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28540)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:405)
at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:178)
```

Does someone please know what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: We can't tell if it's good JSON unless we see it all. And I'd like to think there's no real reason to be accessing the object directly like that, when you could use `JSON.parse()`. Anyway, the one thing I can guess at: Your "working" code declares with `let`, and your other code doesn't. If that's not the problem, then can you link us to a fully reproducible example in TS Playground?

Comment: This is the json https://www.htmlgames.com/rss/games.php?json           I'd look into how to do so! I currently have downloaded the json and saved it in the project, and I don't parse it, I do: import * gamesJson as 'path_to_json'

Comment: I am not able to recreate the error in TS Playground, the error seems to be HOW i use the Json i believe.

Comment: Maybe because i use import * as gamesJson 'path' , maybe i should just fetch it with HTTP and get it from online, should be easy to try. Will update after i've tried this.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you're using the wrong number in the index. Because in Angular the index starts at 0 (0-indexed).

Try to do it:

```
console.log(json[0].name)
```

Comment: exactly, not only angular index, i think all programming language indexes start at zero.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you

Comment: His working example has an index of 1, and he claims his nonworking code fails for all indices from 0 on up. So I don't think this can be the problem.

Comment: I answered it because in part of his answer has: Doing this outputs the correct property: "value". And he was using index 1 that is shown in the JSON in position 0. It's not necessary to downvote my answer :v